# component hiding

Tags: reactjs, dom, routes

In react, There is one component A inside there is one component B I have used. There is one more component C, and inside C there is one button which is when clicked it hides the component B from component A.
How can I achieve this functionality

Comment: It's not super clear, at least a diagrammatic representation or a sample of what you tried so far would really help us help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only React, you can achieve this by:

- Parent/root component to all of these components has a boolean state, let's call it `showComponentB`. It's initialized to `true`.
- This root component passes down the state `showComponentB` as a prop to Component A. In Component A, it is used to either show Component B if `showComponentB` is `true` or hide if it's `false`.
- Root component passes a function to alter the state of `showComponentB` into Component C and is called when the button is clicked.
- State of `showComponentB` is updated in root to `false` and that updated value is passed through to Component A and hides Component B.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Hope it helps you.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CompA> 
       {isVisible && <CompB>
          <CompC clickHandler={()=>setIsVisible(false)}/>
       </CompB> }
      </CompA>
    </div>
  );
}

export const CompA = (props) => {
  return <>
  <div style={{backgroundColor:'red', height:'200px',width:'200px'}}>Component A
  {props.children}
  </div>

</>}

export const CompB = (props) => {
  return <>
  <div style={{backgroundColor:'blue', height:'150px',width:'150px'}}>Component B
  {props.children}
  </div>
  </>
}

export const CompC = (props) => {
  return <>
  <div style={{backgroundColor:'green', height:'100px',width:'100px'}}>Component C
  <button onClick={props.clickHandler}>hide B</button>
  </div>
  </>
}
```